# Label in collection view cell won't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying yo have a label and image show up in collection view cells, but only the image will here's my code

The header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ComicMetadata.h"

@interface ComicCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *page;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *name;

@end
```

The Body

```
#import "ComicCell.h"

@implementation ComicCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self){
  self.page = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
  self.name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
  self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

  self.name.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

  self.name.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];

  self.name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

  [self.contentView addSubview:self.page];

  [self.contentView addSubview:self.name];

  self.name.text = @"Test";
  }
return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  //self.page.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
  self.page.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 234, 312);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? extra text because Stackoverflow doesn't like the code to text ratio

Comment: I'm trying to what you asking but I don't get it :/

Comment: I'm trying to add a label and image to the cell, but only the image shows up

Comment: I think your *label* is under your *imageView* ,can you add first imageView to your superView

Comment: Crap I put the version up from before that change. Sorry I'll edit that. It did not work when I tried it

Comment: Still have problems?

Comment: Could you log `page.frame` and `name.frame`?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by logging them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ComicCell init with frame, the bounds does not init exactly, you must set frame for the label again in layoutSubviews.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.page.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 234, 312);
    self.name.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 234, 312);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly what I needed. I had tried that before, but it didn't work. Whatever it is now.